# linear model to predict pairwise differences in R?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I would like to set up a model where the predictor variables and response variables are pair-wise differences between the subjects. More specifically, I have a set of biological populations and I want to see whether the genetic divergence between any 2 populations significantly predicts the difference in a continuous trait value between those 2 populations. [So each biological population is really an individual subject, not a statistical population]. The model needs to predict pairwise differences because the predictor variable (a measure of genetic distance between populations) is only meaningful in a pairwise context.

Is there a way to set up a glm that models pairwise differences in R? Or should I just calculate the pairwise differences outside the model, and then apply the model to the population of differences? The latter option seems simpler but I am concerned there would be independence issues.

Many thanks for your help, I have not found any relevant info for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There most definitely would be independence issues if you used all pairwise differences among your observations as independent data points in a GLM. Think about it this way- if you have *N* independent observations, you will have (*N*^2 - *N*)/2 pairwise comparisons. For *N*=10, that gives you 45 pairwise comparisons. For *N*=20, that gives you 190 pairwise comparisons. Clearly, you cannot produce (*N*^2 - *N*)/2 independent observations from *N* original observations, so you have a non-independence problem.

To deal with your problem, you might try the method 'multiple regression on distance matrices' implemented in the `MRM` function from the R package `ecodist`. An interesting application of this method can be found [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/ele.12491/full).

Lichstein, J.W. (2007). Multiple regression on distance matrices: a multivariate spatial analysis tool. [Plant Ecol., 188, 117–131.](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11258-006-9126-3#/page-1)

Goslee, S.C. & Urban, D.L. (2007). The ecodist package for dissimilarity-based analysis of ecological data. [J. Stat. Softw., 22, 1–19.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ecodist/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Small addendum to the @slow-loris's answer: for situations like @g-spea's describes, namely to assess the correlation between two matrices of pair-wise distances/differences, a Mantel test is commonly used. You can perform it with function `mantel()` in the R package `vegan` or in `ecodist`. By skimming Lichstein's paper it looks like MRM builds on the partial Mantel test and improves on it, but for two matrices MRM should be equivalent to a standard Mantel test. Indeed, in the following example:

```
library(ecodist)
data(graze)
MRM(dist(LOAR10) ~ dist(sitelocation), data=graze, nperm=10)
# compared to:
mantel(dist(LOAR10) ~ dist(sitelocation), data=graze)
```

The value or R^2 provided by `MRM()` is the square of Mantel's correlation coefficient r provided by `mantel()`. While `mantel()` only provides the Mantel's r and the p values associated to it, `MRM()` also seems to provide regression coefficients (intercept and slope).